# What is SOAP V2 url on Magento 1.7.0.0

Tags: web-services, magento, soap

Is the url for accessing Magento SOAP V2 changed in version 1.7.0.0? When I try to access the service on "http://www.somedomain.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1" in browser it gives an error "Invalid webservice adapter specified."
Is this a bug or am I missing something?
Thanks for any help

Comment: update: it works with /index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1. URL rewrites are set to yes in the beckend, which is strange.

Comment: and are your rewrites working in server level ?

Comment: yes they are working elsewhere on the site.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use

```
http://www.somedomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

instead of

```
http://www.somedomain.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

On 1.7 only the first url works, on 1.6 or lower, the second url also works.

Comment: This may be outdated, but given your comment... Although your answer gets the asker going in the right direction it is still giving them misinformation.  All version of magento that I'm aware of (1.6+) support the second version without index.php.  It is just a matter of configuring things right so that url rewrites are used and index.php is hidden everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different approach if you want to keep compatibility with old API calls. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897296/469995

Answer (score 0):

```
http://xxxx.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

or

```
http://127.1.1.1/magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

---

Writen [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)