# Magento api: Invalid webservice adapter specified

Tags: php, api, magento

Is there anything specific i need to do to get the api in magento working?

I am visiting /api/soap/?wsdl on my local installation (1.7) and it returns the following error:

```
Invalid webservice adapter specified.
```

Everything looks enabled in the site but i cant find any info on other steps i need to do to get the api to work.

Comment: /index.php/api/V2_soap?wsdl=1 have you tried this

Comment: ok so this works only when index.php is included in the url.  Why is this?

Comment: index.php is not necessary, you can try this way too  www.yourmagento.com/api/V2_soap?wsdl=1

Comment: no, thats what i mean.  it only works with index.php in the url.  I have rewrites on and the site works fine without them.  The api is not thoguh

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is SOAP V2 url on Magento 1.7.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479705/what-is-soap-v2-url-on-magento-1-7-0-0)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've solved this from htaccess by turning off MultiViews option like this:

from

```
<Directory /var/www/magento>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/magento>
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Comment: This throws apache error `Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may` So the correct syntax for above should be `Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`

Comment: I get a 500 internal service error when I enable this

Comment: I had to do it in: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Comment: I had to edit the conf file located in `/etc/httpd/vhosts.d/file.conf` and then restart httpd. Thanks for the answer it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a different approach if you want to keep compatibility with old API calls. For some obscure reason, my Apache server doesn't analyze the string `^api/...` during the rewrite parsing.

But you can still use `http://www.somedomain.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1` without changing Magento PHP code. You just need to change the .htaccess like the following:

Replace in .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]`

by

`RewriteRule ^api(\.php)?/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$2 [QSA,L]` (see the ^api.php/ instead of ^api/)

And even better if some of you, have `http://www.somedomain.com/api/V2_soap?wsdl=1` (V2_soap is uppercase), you will have to add a `RewriteMap` to use internal apache function to set in lowercase the parameter. Add to your virtual host the RewriteMap:

`RewriteMap lc int:tolower`

And in the .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^api(\.php)?/([a-zA-Z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=${lc:$2} [QSA,L]`

This will set to lowercase the parameter for the api.php script and also accept 'V2_soap' in the regular expression

This last part has been brought by [@dreeves in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2924084/469995)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by editing in my virtual host file *`(/etc/apache2/sites-available/mag.dev.conf)`* like this:

```
    <Directory /var/www/mag/mag>
      Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      .....
    </Directory>
```

now its loading the xml response.

the platfrom is ubuntu 12.04