# Accessing Magento API with PHP SoapClient results in redirect - Access over browser works

Tags: php, magento, soap, soap-client

I'm accessing the Magento SOAP API v2 with PHP's SoapClient

```
$soap_client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array('trace' => 1));
```

The wsdl url is `http://www.example.org/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1`
Opening the url in the browser results in a valid xml document.
*However* when I access that same url with the SoapClient I get the following error message from `$soap_client->__getLastResponse()`:

```
Invalid webservice adapter specified.
```

Looking at the request headers with `$soap_client->__getLastRequestHeaders()` shows that the call is being redirected to `http://www.example.org/api/v2_soap/index/`:

```
POST /api/v2_soap/index/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.4.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerAction"
Content-Length: 542
```

Calling that url (`http://www.example.org/api/v2_soap/index/`) in the browser outputs the same error message that the SoapClient returns (`Invalid webservice adapter specified.`)

**How is it possible that the `SoapClient` is being redirected while a normal http request works fine?**

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried disabling MultiViews in Apache with .htaccess? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932908/magento-api-invalid-webservice-adapter-specified

Comment: @B00MER Yep, that actually helped. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map
>   which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of
>   them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements.

- [MultiView Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#negotiation)