# Magento API integration with stamps.com / shippingZ (v1.6 and v1.7)

Tags: api, magento, soap, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

We've got an instance of Magento developed (two, in fact, since we tested both 1.6 and 1.7), and we are unable to have stamps.com hit its API. I've checked all the logs in our reverse proxy as well as Apache, and the connection is made, is successful, and it closes OK — so nothing's getting blocked. However, the API call times out, and we get this error when it hits the ShippingZmagento.php:

```
<Error>
   <Code>1</Code>
   <Description>Please, make sure that you use right URL. Url is case sensitive</Description>
   <MessageDetails>http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl</MessageDetails>
   <Version>3.0.0.55618</Version>
</Error>
```

The FQDN is correct, and I'm about to hit the WSDL directly just fine as well — so it seems like a bad address translation might be happening at the API level or something.

We've tried it out in the DMZ with a couple of test domains (both with domains and subdomains), to no avail.

Any thoughts any of you might be able to shine on this would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a bad questions — but I'm not sure what's being asked here.   I don't know which side (you/stamps.com) is sending or receiving data, I don't know when/the context of this happening, and I don't know what extensions (if any) you're using to do this, and I don't know what `ShippingZmagento.php` is (as it's not a part of the core Magento installation)  People other than me will need this information to help.

Answer (score 0):

Open up stamps.com's php files and search for wsdl references they will need to updated to work on 1.7 magento:

[What is SOAP V2 url on Magento 1.7.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479705/what-is-soap-v2-url-on-magento-1-7-0-0)